# Glyph hacking failure same as normal hack?

Tags: ingress

Are there any consequences in a total failure when glyph hacking as opposed to just hacking normally? Or is a total failure essentially the same as a normal hack?

Comment: What hacking do you mean, as in the bad hacking or a hacking that is **meant to be** in the game?

Comment: @ExplosionsPlus [Hacking](http://decodeingress.me/ingress-manual/ingress-portals/hack-portal/) is a primary feature of gameplay, it's in-game lingo. This isn't related to cheating.

Comment: Sorry, I was just checking if this was illegal or not. Didn't play the game, so don't know whats in it, therefore asking if it was a feature in the game.

Comment: @ExplosionsPlus No worries, it sounds a bit sketchy if you're not familiar with the game.

Comment: I'm not leaving this as an actual answer because I don't have any way to back it up (hack results being semi-random, after all), but it's always appeared to me that total glyph hack failure is the same as a normal hack. And, indeed, it says "0%" bonus. It doesn't list any penalty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Glyph hacking is intended to be a bonus to your normal hacking. It rewards your speed and (muscle) memory by giving you drops **in addition** to what you'd normally get from hacking. So no, there's no other consequence if you fail to reproduce the sequence that's been proposed to you.

Comment: Except, of course, not getting the bonus.

Answer (score 4):

While Kappei is correct to say that there is no items penalty for failing a glyph back, there is the obvious time penalty - while a normal hack I'd just one tap on the scanner, a glyph hack is long press... wait... see glyphs... wait... trace glyphs. If you're in an even moderately dense portal field, that means you can't hack every portal without stopping walking. If you're not getting any extra items out of the hack, that's going to dramatically slow down your item collection rate *per unit time*.

Comment: I had considered this as well. Unfortunately, too many portals isn't a problem I'm suffering from.